# Generating a list of selects for filtering

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a problem creating a dynamic number of select to use for filtering an ng-repeat.

I'm loading from a JSON object that looks like this:

```
[
    {"filter":"Age",
        "options": ["Young", "Middle-aged", "Old"]
    },
    {"filter":"Color",
        "options": ["Blue", "Red", "Yellow"]
    }
]
```

I don't have access to the code I used to generate the HTML, but I can get the selects and options formatted correctly using ng-repeat or ng-options, but no matter what, I can't get it to actually filter my data. If I just hard code the HTML for the select, it works fine, so the only difference is that in the generated version, there's an extra div on the outside with the ng-repeat line. Sorry that I don't have the code on me, but I can try to write up something similar if someone needs to see something similar to it.
Essentially, the final product, if I just hard code it, looks like this and if I generate it, the outside div just has an extra `ng-repeat="person in people"`.

```
<div>
    <label>Age:</label>                                                                  
    <select ng-model="query.age">
        <option value="Young">Young</option>                                                  
        <option value="Middle-aged">Middle-aged</option>                                 
        <option value="Old">Old</option>                                                  
    </select>
</div>
```

I think the problem is because of scoping. I found that if I just have `{{person.age}}` somewhere on the page, it works in the hard coded version and not in the generated, but I don't know what the best way to fix it is. I know that child scopes can't directly be accessed by parent scopes, so I was wondering what the best way to structure this would be.

EDIT:
This [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hn46pD2FbDjvjJI485Ep?p=preview) is what I mean. I can't get generated selects to work at a filter. If I hard code them, it works fine, but just the generated ones don't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

ANGULAR:

```
angular
    .module('testApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.items = 
            [
                {"filter":"Age",
                    "options": ["Young", "Middle-aged", "Old"]
                },
                {"filter":"Color",
                    "options": ["Blue", "Red", "Yellow"]
                }
            ];
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <label>{{ item.filter }}:</label>
    <select ng-options="o for o in item.options"
            ng-model="item.selected"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PlwPaHnSBZPxNrbzJFQB?p=preview)

**UPDATE**
If you want to apply a filter on this you can use the following code in the ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people | filter: (items | filter: { filter: 'age' })[0].selected">
  {{ person.name }}
</div>
```

Updated [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fGu1pAwQL0XMXeiEjGUJ?p=preview)

Comment: I had something similar to that, but my problem is that I'm not sure how to get a filter working on that now.

[Plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/hn46pD2FbDjvjJI485Ep)

 Like this, for example.

Comment: I have updated my answer showing how you can get a filter working based on your plnkr

Comment: This is almost exactly what I'm looking for, but I have two more follow up questions to that. Is there a way to get the filter to only work the corresponding attribute of the person? For example, in your updated Plnkr, if a person had a color `"Middle-aged Yellow"` or something like that, the results would also show that person, even if their age was something else. The second question is if there's a way to get rid of the "age" keyword in the updated filter. My end goal is to get all these filters created dynamically, so having to type in the filter is not what I want.

Comment: I am not sure if that can be done in the View but you can do it in the Controller. You can call a function to filter the list on the `ng-change` event on the `<select />`. I have updated the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/V5GkPAw3Rll0yHJX2zDT?p=preview) with an example showing this. So, when 'Young' and 'Blue' are selected then only 'Jake' will show.